# Symfony (3.4) app : cant redirect requests to /web dir via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, server

I've a website lets say **website.fr** ( on server : `/web/website` ) ;
I ve added a symfony blog app in `/web/website/blog/`.

I dont manage to access the blog via **website.fr/blog/** (404 error)

There is a .htaccess file in `/web/website/blog/` directory, and one in `/web/website/blog/web` directory.

I am used to deploy symfony apps 'alone' on a server, and make the domain point to the web dir of the app, and everything always works fine, but in this configuration, I cant get it to work.

I have tried to use the following .htaccess conf under `/web/website/blog/` :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And I did not edit the default one under `/web/website/blog/web/`

Im not sure what Im doing wrong, so any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get what I wanted, but here is the solution I implemented :

I created a .htaccess in /web/website dir, that rewrites all requests to /web/website/blog, with the root (/) excluded from this rewriting :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/web/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

That's not the way I wanted to get my rewriting, but I have the result I expected ; note that it would not be a good solution for a website that would evolve with new modules, routes, folders...

Answer (score 0):

For me I use .. nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```js
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web
    <Directory /var/www/project/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

which is explained [**Here**](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/web_server_configuration.html) and restart Apache, but I do not know if I understand your problem

Comment: thanks, but I need to use a .htaccess, not virtualhost